# Angular Material: Textarea with fixed height

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to have a page which has two main components. On the upper half a `textarea` on the lower half some input fields. The split should be 50:50. The problem I'm facing:

I cannot tell the `textarea` to fill the complete height when displayed. I know I can use some `cdk..MinRows` or `...MaxRows` but therefore I need to know the whole height before. Additionally the underline looks also quite strange, e.g.

[image]

How to fix it? Does it work with `Material` or should I use plain HTML `textarea`? My [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxrxfi?file=src/app/button-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Any reason not to just give the textarea height: 100% in CSS? The 'underline' is just showing the bottom of the area and changes when it is focused.

Comment: Hmmm the `height:100%` fixes  the height - which is great. I've update the sample. Nevertheless as a user I would wonder why the underline is displayed.  Especially since its next to the button. As a user I would either expect the line at the very bottom or the button aligned with the underline. The result looks quite strange - although I agree its much better.

Comment: If you inspect the element you should be able to find out how to get rid of the underline (which is likely not an actual underline but something like a border).